# Disable Webview in Console Application

Tags: vb.net, .net-6.0

I'm building a NET6 local multiplatform console application as shown:

[image]

But even with a single "Hello World" and without any reference or package being called, **everytime I debug-execute the code** a lot of "Webview2" is loaded on the Windows processes.

[image]

Worst: **even stoping the debug session, these modules remains active** and they seems to close only if i manually finalize them in Task Manager

Since the application is not an ASP.NET nor a Winform application, why Visual Studio 2022 loads Webview2?

Can I disable it?

Comment: I can't replicate this issue with a new Console app, so what do you reference which brings WebView2 in? Any reference to Microsoft.Web?

Comment: Really no. It's a console with some Nuget packages only but without anything related to Javascript or Web and so forth. My packages are: Sodium.Core, Rebex.Security.Full, System.Data.Sqlite, LZ4Net and Hardware.info. - I will try to edit my post and show the refereces VS2022 shows to me.

Comment: By multiplatform you mean this .NET Core?

Comment: Yes, NET CORE 6

Comment: Interesting, I added all your packages and can't replicate (except Rebex.Security.Full which I can't find)

Comment: I'll try to locate a shareware of it - my package is official and it was added from a local folder. But I'm sure it isn't the problem....  look here https://www.nuget.org/profiles/rebex